# problem with reasonable question asking

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I've been in learning Java for only a few months now. I've NEVER become an advanced coder, though I've learned the beginnings of a FEW languages but don't really remember them that well. I know that if I ask too many questions without contributing to the site, I won't be allowed to ask anymore.

On the other hand, I'm definitely NOT a very experienced coder, so I have trouble answering people's questions. How do I contribute to the site? Will it matter if I contribute to another of the stack exchange forums besides overflow, or am I just expected to be able to answer something for someone? What can I do about this?

Comment: If you never answer a question (and even if you do answer a question), you'll *only* be banned because your questions are bad. If you have great questions, there's no problem.

Comment: My questions are usually about my Java textbook or robotics. Robotics ended for the year, so if that's where the bad questions are coming from, I'm absolutely sure I won't be asking anything more about Gosu or anything. Still, I would like to know what questions I've been asking that are bad please.

Comment: Wait, are you question banned? Or are you just trying to prevent yourself from being question banned?

Comment: I've been question banned for a while. I'm trying to figure out a way to contribute so I don't have to be and so it won't happen again.

Comment: @user3251611 you can suggest edits that correct several grammar and spelling errors or fixing dead links. For every such useful edit (that is, not a minor change, and not changing the actual code) you get 2 points.

Comment: How many questions have you deleted (or have been deleted for you)?

Comment: I haven't DELETED the questions. I didn't know I had to do that. I guess there's no point in them being online. I think I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: Deleting the questions makes it worse, actually. Improve them the best you can, and hopefully they'll get upvoted and determined good by the community.

Comment: **Whoa! Stop! Deletion is *bad* in terms of the ban.**

Comment: Right, I wasn't suggesting you should delete any questions (and you certainly shouldn't), I was curious how many questions have been deleted that we can't see in your profile, since the questions we can see don't seem too bad (at least in terms of down-votes).

Comment: Related: [Best way for an SO newbie to contribute answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63322), [What's the best way to contribute to Stack Overflow if you don't have a ton of technical knowledge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17016)

Comment: I've just looked over your questions. You write coherent, complete sentences and explain your problems fairly cleary, so you're already doing pretty well! Your main difficulty seems to be treating SO as a forum-like space, where you post "threads", referring back to previous threads, and ask a bit too much in each one. You need to focus on each question as a completely discrete unit, standing on its own, describing a very particular issue, and be very specific about what you understand and what you don't.

Comment: @Josh agreed, but I don't think the questions that are there now justify a ban, unless there were a lot more down-votes that have since been offset, or there are a ton of flags, or deleted questions we can't see, etc.

Comment: Yes, I assume there are hidden questions, @AaronBertrand, although I believe that asking a certain number of questions (maybe in a given shory period of time) that don't get any upvotes is also a ban factor.